# RJDBC dbWriteTable "expected logical" Error

Tags: r

while trying to execute the following R code:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4),b=c("a", "b", "c", "d"));
dbWriteTable(conn, "HDO.TEST", df,overwrite=TRUE,append = T)
dbCommit(conn);
```

I got the following error:

```
Error in .valueClassTest(standardGeneric("dbWriteTable"), "logical", "dbWriteTable") :
  invalid value from generic function ‘dbWriteTable’, class “NULL”, expected “logical”
```

I'm wondering why this could happen

Comment: Change `append =T` to `append = TRUE` ?

Comment: I'm getting the same error, but the write completed successfully.  It appears the database is not returning a TRUE/FALSE response (indicating success/failure) that is expected by `dbWriteTable`.

Answer (score 0):

From the help of 'dbWriteTable' of DBI,

> If the overwrite argument is TRUE, an existing table of the same name
>   will be overwritten. This argument doesn't change behaviour if the
>   table does not exist yet.
>
> If the append argument is TRUE, the rows in an existing table are
>   preserved, and the new data are appended. If the table doesn't exist
>   yet, it is created.

Now, if overwrite = T and append = T then the code is asked to perform the following contradict functions:

1. Over Write the existing table.
2. Don't overwrite and append the new rows to the existing table.

Probably, this is way the code is throwing error.